# Xubuntu 12.10; battery drains when laptop lid is closed

Tags: 12.10, xubuntu, battery, xscreensaver

I am on Xubuntu 12.10. When I close my laptop lid, the screen goes black as normal, and the normal login window appears when I open it up again. However, I notice that for example, I left my laptop closed for no more than about 45 mintues, yet my battery had drained more than 30%. The same thing happened to me the previous night, where I left my laptop lid closed the whole night at around 50, 60%, yet dead by morning. I use xscreensaver. Are there any settings I need to change? I have no background processes running as far as I know.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Your laptop keeps running when you close the lid. Perhaps you want to reconfigure it to suspend (sleep) automatically when you close the lid?

Comment: edit: thank you, suspend worked perfectly with no battery drain.