# Battery drain when lid closed. Two lenovo thinkpads, nearly identical. One is fine the other not. How to diff/debug?

Tags: suspend, power-management, battery

These are both Thinkpad Carbon X1 nearly identical. I've changed the BIOS, done some grub twiddle etc.

```
cat /sys/power/mem_sleep 
[s2idle] deep
```

This should be correct I think?

The thing is I have access to a nearly identical system that appears to be ok (no overnight drain to zero). Am wondering how to diff these two systems methodically? Or just a hail mary guess could also be useful here.

Potentially related:

- [Xubuntu 12.10; battery drains when laptop lid is closed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253237/xubuntu-12-10-battery-drains-when-laptop-lid-is-closed)
- [Battery drain during suspend mode, when lid is closed (~20% in 8 hours)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398674/battery-drain-during-suspend-mode-when-lid-is-closed-20-in-8-hours)
- [Battery drains even while laptop lid closed (Ubuntu 19.04 & Thinkpad X1 Carbon 6th gen)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156871/battery-drains-even-while-laptop-lid-closed-ubuntu-19-04-thinkpad-x1-carbon-6)
- [Ubuntu not is hibernating when lid is closed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291903/ubuntu-not-is-hibernating-when-lid-is-closed)

One additional weird thing is that on the drainy system, chrome seems to freeze for several seconds at a time.

I also see rmi4_f34 rmi4-00.fn34: rmi_f34v7_probe: Unrecognized bootloader version: 13 (

in dmesg on the drainy system.

I haven't fully properly diffed dmesg on the machines but I guess I could do that with some work.

I could I guess try booting to windows and doing another round of driver updates as well. Not sure ... I would expect to see power errors.

UPDATE:

I think the following resolved this:

- check BIOS sleep state. This was wrong on the misbehaving machine.
- edit grub as below (reboot)

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep"
```

or deep should be s2idle. Not sure.

Comment: Two questions spring to mind: (0) Which version(s) of Ubuntu are you using? (1) What is the swap configuration like on these machines? 